# Pagination and filtering

Tags: reactjs, pagination

I make a website with movies. I have a page where all films are displayed, there is a working pagination, there are filters.
The fact is that I can not apply filters and page navigation at the same time. The data comes to different handlers from one of the forms, another from pagination.

How to combine the data to submit? So that the data from the form and pagination go to reducer together.

If I apply filters, and then go to the second page, then the filters will be reset, since they go separately from each other.

```js
const Discvoer = props => {
 
//send number from pagination
  let nextPage = num => {
    let data = {
      
      num: num
    };
    props.Get(data);
  };
//send data from form
  let onChange = info => {
    let data = {
      Sort: info.Sort,
      Year: info.Year,
      Genres: info.Genres,
      KeyWords: info.KeyWords,
    };
    props.Get(data);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.Discvoer}>
      <div className={classes.filter}>
        <FilterForm {...props} onChange={onChange}></FilterForm>
      </div>
   .....
      <div>
        {TotalPages > 1 && (
          <Paginator
            TotalResults={props.Films.total_results}
            currentPage={props.Films.page}
            nextPage={nextPage} gets number of page
          ></Paginator>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I am not sure about your problem, but I strongly recommended you to use a good react component-based framework,  https://ant.design/components/table/ or material UI

Comment: @Jaison Explain why i must use they?

Comment: For the one reason is any liabrary / framwork with the large community will get more attention for the issues/usability question within it.